# How to keep Aptana tests in a single tab?

Tags: firefox, testing, aptana, aptana3

Each time I run or debug a webpage in Aptana, it opens a new tab or window in Firefox. After several runs, there are either a Firefox window with more than one tabs or multiple Firefox windows.

How could I let the Firefox reload a tab for each test run, instead of open a new tab/window each time?

Answer (score 0):

You could just "save all changes" instead of make a test run. Then reload the page on firefox.